# how can I make this Swift event handler boilerplate more concise?

Tags: swift, events, design-patterns

I've seen a pattern in Java that lets you implement a subset of a list of callbacks, in a type-safe way, inline with the class that uses the callbacks:

```
registerHandlers(new ClassWithNoOpMethods() {
    @override
    public void onFooEvent(FooEvent event) { ... }
    @override
    public void onBarEvent(BarEvent event) { ... }
}
```

All nice and type-safe. I'd like to do the same thing in Swift, but some googling didn't turn up any (IMHO) elegant solutions. So I came up with this:

```
let registrar = EventSource.getEventRegistrar()
registrar.onFooEvent = { event in doSomethingFoo(event) }
registrar.onBarEvent = { event in doSomethingBar(event) }
...
EventSource.removeEventCallbacks(registrar)
```

This works fine for consuming the events - its just the subset of events I'm interested in, it lets me define the code inline, etc etc.

However, when I actually implemented this, I got a lot of repeated, boilerplate, non-DRY code. It offends me, but I can't figure out a better way to implement the scheme shown above. I'd like to appeal to the Swift gods on StackOverflow to show me a more concise way to implement this.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
public class Phone {
    ...phone stuff...
    public class PhoneEventRegistrar {

        let phone : Phone

        init(phone : Phone) {
            self.phone = phone
        }

        public typealias OnErrorCallback = (PhoneErrorType, String) -> Void
        private var onErrorValue : OnErrorCallback?
        public var onError : OnErrorCallback {
            get { return onErrorValue != nil ? onErrorValue! : {_,_ in} }
            set {
                assert(onErrorValue == nil, "onError cannot be set twice")
                onErrorValue = newValue
            }
        }
        func invokeErrorCallback(type : PhoneErrorType, message : String) {
            if let onErrorValue = onErrorValue {
                onErrorValue(type, message)
            }
        }

        public typealias OnCallStateChangeCallback = (CallState) -> Void
        private var onCallStateChangeValue : OnCallStateChangeCallback?
        public var onCallStateChange : OnCallStateChangeCallback {
            get { return onCallStateChangeValue != nil ? onCallStateChangeValue! : {_ in} }
            set {
                assert(onCallStateChangeValue == nil, "onCallStateChange cannot be set twice")
                onCallStateChangeValue = newValue
            }
        }
        func invokeCallStateChangeCallback(state : CallState) {
            if let onCallStateChangeValue = onCallStateChangeValue {
                onCallStateChangeValue(state)
            }
        }

        // and the mostly-similar code shown twice above is repeated for
        // each possible callback
    }

    func invokeErrorCallbacks(type : PhoneErrorType, message : String) {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }
        registrars.forEach({$0.invokeErrorCallback(type, message: message)})
    }

    func invokeCallStateChangeCallbacks(state : CallState) {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }
        registrars.forEach({$0.invokeCallStateChangeCallback(state)})
    }

    // again, the mostly similar block of code shown twice above is
    // repeated for each possible callback

    private var registrars : [PhoneEventRegistrar] = []
    public func getPhoneEventRegistrar() -> PhoneEventRegistrar {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }
        let registrar = PhoneEventRegistrar(phone: self)
        registrars.append(registrar)
        return registrar
    }

    public func removeRegistrarCallbacks(registrar : PhoneEventRegistrar) {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }
        assert(registrars.contains({$0 === registrar}), "cannot remove callbacks, no matching PhoneEventRegistrar found")
        registrars = registrars.filter({$0 !== registrar})
    }
}
```

If folks see an alternative implementation that has the same usability benefits for the event consumers, i'd love to see those too. Here are some of the other options I've thought of or tried:

- implement a protocol defining the callbacks. Have event consumers implement the protocol and register that for callbacks. Negative: requires all methods to be implemented - forces too many no-op callbacks.
- as above, but extend the protocol with default blank implementations. Negative: still requires the event consumer to implement an extra class for the callbacks. Also, lack of dynamic dispatch for protocol extensions means registering the protocol will force generated events to go to the no-op implementation instead of the real event handler.
- set the consuming class as a delegate on the event producer. Negative: still have to implement no-op callbacks. I've only ever seen one delegate per event producer, and I need several. @Darko comments below are prompting me to consider this option further.

Comment: Best way would be to have delegate pattern in this case using protocols.

Comment: I looked into a protocol-based approach, but hit a series of roadblocks. Some were surmountable, but in the end I wasn't able to produce something with usability similar to the java and swift schemes described above. If you can do so, I'd love to see it as an answer to this question.

Comment: Please show the problems of your Protocol based approach.

Comment: And - has the solution to be a pure Swift approach (only Swift standard library) or is NSFoundation with Obj-C runtime also ok?

Comment: Because currently you seem to be restricted to pure Swift. Which is ok, just need to know.

Comment: If NSFoundation is ok - have you already considered using the obvious NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: Also I still don't get clearly the advantage of the Java solution. Could you explain? Implementing only a subset of callbacks inside the using class is the usual Obj-C delegate pattern, which depends on the Obj-C runtime but is quite elegant.

Comment: @Darko thanks! Some answers here, some I'll add to the question: I believe some objective-c is OK, although I don't have any right now. I would want to keep it inside my framework though, I don't want to force the consumers of my framework to do extra work. Your NSNotificationCenter suggestion is interesting; I will definitely check it out. You should post that as an answer here.

Comment: @Darko doesn't the delegate pattern require implementing all the methods of the delegate? Also, I've only ever seen an event producer have a single delegate to receive calls, although your comment prompts me to wonder if that's really required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NSNotificationCenter

There are multiple solutions for your problem. One could be to simply use  `NSNotificationCenter` instead of implementing your own event mechanism.

With `NSNotificationCenter` you can register for events:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
self,
selector: #selector(MyClass.myMethod),
name: "com.mycompany.myEvent1",
object: userData)
```

And send events from anywhere:

```
let userData: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [anyObject: anyDataToSend]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotificationName("com.mycompany.myEvent1", object: userData)
```

You will find plenty of tutorials on SO and Google regarding NSNotificationCenter.

### Delegate with optional protocol

Another method would be to use the delegate pattern. Create a protocol and mark it as `@objc`, in this way protocol methods can be marked as "optional".

```
@objc protocol MyEventProtocol: class {
  optional func foo() -> Bool
  func bar()
}
```

Every object which conforms to this protocol now must implement bar() but *can* implement optionally foo().

```
class MyEventReceiver: MyEventProtocol {
    func bar() { // do something }
}
```

Then your event sender class can do something like this:

```
class MyEventSender {
     weak var delegate: MyEventProtocol? // the name "delegate" is just convention, you can use any other name

     init(receiver: MyEventReceiver) {
         self.delegate = receiver
     }

     func sendEventToReceiver() {
         if let delegate = self.delegate {
             delegate.func() // guaranteed by the protocol
             delegate.foo?() // foo is marked as optional, so you have to check it with ?. If foo is implemented on the receiver it will be called, otherwise not.
         }
     }
}
```

That's the basic principle. In this way you can define one protocol for all possible events but the implementer of the protocol only have to implement the methods which are not marked as `optional`. They are "required".

### Protocol extensions with default methods

A third method would be to create a protocol extension with default methods.

```
protocol MyEventProtocol: {
  func bar()
}

extension MyEventProtocol {
    func foo() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then the implementor of MyEventProtocol does not have to implement foo() because there is already an implementation. (it's a kind of a "faked"  `@objc` protocol with optional methods) If you add some generic mechanism to this solution you could also prevent the hefty code duplication. (generics in Protocols are done with `associatedtype` in Swift 2.2, see other tutorials)

Comment: These are all good points, and technical issues aside, I do really want to utilize mechanisms that a normal iOS developer will recognize and be comfortable with.